# Extract a substring from a column and replace column data frame

Tags: python, regex

I need some help extracting a substring from a column in my data frame and then replacing that column with a substring. I was wondering if python would be better performance for stripping the string or using regular expression to substitute/replace the string with the substring.

The string looks something like this in the column:

```
Person
------
<Person 1234567 Tom Brady>
<Person 456789012 Mary Ann Thomas>
<Person 92145 John Smith>
```

What I would like is this:

```
Person
------
Tom Brady
Mary Ann Thomas
John Smith
```

What I have so far as far as regular expressions go is this:

```
/^([^.]+[.]+[^.]+)[.]/g
```

And that just gets this part '<Person 1234567 ', not sure how to get the '>' from the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ways, but you can use `str.replace()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Person': ['<Person 1234567 Tom Brady>',
                              '<Person 456789012 Mary Ann Thomas>',
                              '<Person 92145 John Smith>']})
df['Person'] = df['Person'].str.replace(r'(?:<Person[\d\s]+|>)', '', regex=True)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
            Person
0        Tom Brady
1  Mary Ann Thomas
2       John Smith
```

---

Pattern used: `(?:<Person[\d\s]+|>)`, see an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6jgGjt/1):

- `(?:` - Open non-capture group for alternation;

  - `<Person[\d\s]+` - Match literal '<Person' followed by 1+ whitespace characters or digits;
  - `|` - Or;
  - `>` - A literal '>'
  - `)` - Close group.

Answer (score 1):

Python regex has a function called `search` that finds the matching pattern in a string. With the examples given, you can use regex to extract the names with:

```
import re
s = "<Person 1234567 John Smith>"
re.search("[A-Z][a-z]+(\s[A-Z][a-z]+)+", s).group(0)
>>> 'John Smith'
```

The regular expression `[A-Z][a-z]+(\s[A-Z][a-z]+)+` is just matching the names (Tom Brady, Mary Ann Thomas, etc.)

I like to use Panda's `apply` function to apply an operation on each row, so the final result would look like this:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

def extract_name(row):
    row["Person"] = re.search("[A-Z][a-z]+(\s[A-Z][a-z]+)+", row["Person"]).group(0)
    return row

df = YOUR DATAFRAME
df2 = df.apply(extract_name, axis=1)
```

and `df2` has the Person column with the extracted names.

Answer (score 1):

You can first identify all the alphabets in keeping things simple with this code

```
res =  re.findall(r"[^()0-9-]+", string)
res[1]
```

This should return you a list of strings `['Person', 'Tom Brady']`, you can then access the name of the Person with `res[1]`

***Remark: I have yet to try the code, in the case that it also returns spaces, you should be able to easily remove them with `strip()` or it should be the the third string of the list `res[3]` instead.*

You can read more about `re.findall()` online or through the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).